# Combining mousenter / mouseleave into one function

Tags: jquery

Consider these two working functions. Is there any way to string these two together into one jQuery function?

```
$("#help").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({bottom: '+=100',});
});

$("#help").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({bottom: '-=100',});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$("#help").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        bottom: '+=100',
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        bottom: '-=100',
    });
});​
```

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave
>   events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during
>   the time the mouse is within the element. Calling `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, > handlerOut)` is shorthand for: `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#help").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {

});
```

alternatively used:

```
$('#help').hover(
  function() {
     // code for mouseenter 
     $(this).animate({bottom: '+=100',});
  },

  function() {
    // code for mouseleave
    $(this).animate({bottom: '-=100',});
  }
);
```